# How to get anonymous values from a thread's stackframe (Java Debug Interface/JDI)

Tags: java, debugging, interface, anonymous

Note: This is regarding the Java Debug Interface (JDI).

I know there's the option to get a thread's stackframe, and from that a list of all visible variables and their values. However, I don't know how to get anonymous values, that is values not stored in a variable but "internally" on the stack (or maybe something else?).

Things like results from if-evaluations, comparisons, etc. For instance let's say we have this in our code:

```
if(array[i] > x)
```

How/where is that piece of data (i.e. the result: true or false) stored at runtime and what classes or methods within the JDI provide me access to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to get them without dropping down to debugging at the bytecode level is to change your code to assign them to a variable. Sorry, but that's the way it's designed; if it doesn't have a name it doesn't necessarily last long enough to get out of the execution stack and into a variable, and the debugger is designed to work on the latter, not the former.

Or ask the debugger for the values of `x`, `i`, and (once you know `i`), `array[i]` and do the computation/comparison yourself.

Or, in this case, simply watch what branch the `if` takes.

Comment: thanks keshlam! If I may I would ask a followup question, because I'm completely new to JDI: I would obviously have to parse/check the source code related to the execution. I know JDI can give me the source file and position within it, but just so that I don't make myself unneccessary work: Can JDI give me the source code directly, or do I have to parse out that stuff from the source files myself? Thanks!